super().__init__("py_test") causes "None" cannot be assigned to parameter
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node


class MyNode(Node):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__("py_test")
    self.counter_ = 0
    self.get_logger().info("Hello ROS2")
    self.create_timer(0.5, self.timer_callback)

def timer_callback(self):
    self.counter_ += 1
    self.get_logger().info("Hello " + str(self.counter_))


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = MyNode()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This it my ROS2 code from a udemy course.
when I typed super().init("py_test"), VS code showed a red line under it.
I restarted the course after a long time, But when I did it the first time, VS code didn't show any error. It shows now.

Please post the solution as an answer and not as a postscript to the question. This is a Q&A site, please take the [tour] to better understand how SE operates. Thanks.

It seems, the ROS2 team have updated the ROS2 since then. I'm using the ROS2 humble but it might go for any distro, where VS code shows a red underline under the code of the init line.
Even though it shows as an error in VS code, the code works as intended.
but to fix that, change that line into
super().__init__("py_test", parameter_overrides = [])

A parameter override is something to do with the parameters, where we manually force a parameter into the code itself for debugging purposes or something.
but adding that removes the red underline shown by the VS code.

Thanks for posting the answer. You probably need to remove the duplicate text on your question.
